# Add column with hardcoded values in PowerBI

Tags: powerbi, dax

It's probably extremely simple but I can't find an answer. I have created a new column and I would like to use the DAX syntax to fill the column with hardcoded values.

I can write this: `Column = 10` and I will get a column of 10s but let's say my table has 3 rows and I would like to insert a column with `[10, 17, 155]`. How can I do that?

Comment: Why don't you use Power Query to add the column to the table???

Comment: @teylyn I would like to easily change the values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using DATATABLE function

`Table = DATATABLE("Column Name",INTEGER,{{10},{17},{155}})`

You can also put more columns with their own data if you want to, check this
 https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/datatable-function

Comment: Thanks but the table is already created... how can I add a column to an existing table?

Comment: Let's say my table has already one column: `Table = (GENERATESERIES(1,3))` How can I add a second column with the values?

Comment: If you can see the query for the table why not edit it with the above query. However you will have to put hard coded values instead of using the generate series function.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your table has a primary key column, say, `ID`, you could create a new table with just the column you want to manually input.

```
ID  Value
---------
1   10
2   17
3   155
```

You can create this table either through the Enter Data button or create it using the DAX `DATATABLE` function as @Deltapimol suggests.

Once you have this table you can create a relationship to your existing table in the data model at which point you can either use this new table in your report to get the values you need or if you really need them in the existing table for some reason, you can pull them over using the [`RELATED` function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/related-function-dax) in a calculated column.

---

```
Table1 = GENERATESERIES(1, 3)
Table2 = DATATABLE(
             "ID", INTEGER,
             "Value" INTEGER,
             {{1, 10},{2, 17},{3, 155}}
         )
```

Now you can create a relationship from `Table1` to `Table2[ID]` and then define a calculated column on `Table1` as follows:

```
 ValueFromTable2 = RELATED(Table2[Value])
```

If you don't want to create a relationship, then you could use the [`LOOKUPVALUE` function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/lookupvalue-function-dax) instead in a calculated column on `Table11`.

Comment: Like I said, you could create the new calculated column on your existing table using `RELATED'.